# Why my smart card accepts two different keys as its MAC key?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, 3des, parity, globalplatform

As you see below, I tried to list installed applets on my card using **gp -list**. I specify some different key:

```
GP: gp -mac 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F -list
AID: A000000151000000 (|....Q...|)
     ISD OP_READY: Security Domain, Card lock, Card terminate, Default selected,
 CVM (PIN) management

AID: A0000001515350 (|....QSP|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     A000000151535041 (|....QSPA|)


GP: gp -mac 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4E -list
AID: A000000151000000 (|....Q...|)
     ISD OP_READY: Security Domain, Card lock, Card terminate, Default selected,
 CVM (PIN) management

AID: A0000001515350 (|....QSP|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     A000000151535041 (|....QSPA|)


GP: gp -mac 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4D -list
openkms.gp.GPException: External authenticate failed SW: 6982
        at openkms.gp.GlobalPlatform.check(GlobalPlatform.java:924)
        at openkms.gp.GlobalPlatform.openSecureChannel(GlobalPlatform.java:447)
        at openkms.gp.GPTool.main(GPTool.java:280)
```

Why it works fine with two different keys?

> 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4**F**

and

> 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4**E**

Note that I tried some other cards and tools! Same output.

Is this because of that the encryption with both keys has the same output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only flipping the parity bit which is not used nor checked by the card (or software). Which means the outcome of ciphers is the same, yes.

Comment: Wow! I tested some other keys. Is the least significant bit in each byte for parity? In the other word, does each key has 2^16 equal pair?!

Comment: @Am1r: Yes, for all DES-family keys every byte has this parity-bit., which is the reason, that single-DES has only 56 and triple-DES 168 effective key bits.

Comment: @guidot Should not it be checked by the card? I mean why the card ignore it?

Comment: @Am1r You are right, of course, and some implementations perform the check.. But the times of manually typing in a key from a piece of paper or a serial line transmission have passed.No RSA or elliptic curve key format provides a similar mechanism (short of a full signed certificate), even if the (in case of RSA substantially) longer key sizes leave much more room for errors.